# addslashes when using a / character?

Tags: php, mysql, vb6

I am inserting data into a database and i need to do the following string...

```
Text 1 t/a Text 2
```

do i need to use `addslashes` function when inserting using PHP for the `/` character?

I did try without and the addslashes function which inserts into the database fine however when i run a query in my visual basic program i get an error message saying Command Failed and i think its because of the `/` character

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Use [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) and you don't need `addslashes` function.

Comment: i use PDO in my code but when the query runs in visual basic it has that error because of the / character

Comment: The problematic query could be useful

Answer (score 1):

You should almost never use `addslashes`. Most times when it might be useful, there is a more specific general escaping function available (or, occasionally, one needs to be written).

If you are inserting into a database, then you should usually be handling your escaping [using parameterized queries (via prepared statements)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/19068).

Answer (score 0):

`addslashes` is unsafe for SQL and you should *never* use it in that context. Use parameterized queries instead as Quentin suggests.

In any case your problem is not the forward slash `/` because that character has no special meaning in SQL string literals. Your problem is caused by something else.